# show that $\sum P(x,y) e^{x^2 + y^2}$ is a modular form over $\Gamma_0(4)$ where $P(x,y) = x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4$

Tags: fourier-analysis, modular-forms, spherical-harmonics, theta-functions

In these lecture notes of Zagier, I read that generalized theta functions are still modular forms.  Let $q = e^{2\pi i z}$

$$\theta(z) = \sum_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}} \Big[ x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4 \Big] \, q^{x^2 + y^2} \tag{$\ast$}$$ is a modular form over $\Gamma_0(4)$.  In the one-variables case we argue using Poisson summation, e.g. the identity:

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi n^2 t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi n^2 / t} $$

Since this is Poisson summation for $f(x) = e^{-x^2 t} $.  Is there any analogous Poisson-summation identity we can use here or this generalized $\theta$ funnction in ($\ast$)?

---

Also if anyone can help, I am still confused by the jargon.

- is this a **cusp form** ?
- is this a **Maass waveform** ?

Comment: My best guess this comes from $f(x,y) = P(x,y) e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ and saying 
$$  \sum_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} f(x,y) = \sum_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \hat{f}(x,y)$$ which is Poisson summation in two variables and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a [lattice dual](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/DualLattice.pdf) to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sense of "generalized" (theta series) is that the polynomial coefficients should be *harmonic* (for exponentials of the form $e^{2\pi i(m^2+n^2)}$ or the $N$-dimensional analogue) and homogeneous of total degree $d$. The resulting modular form is of weight ${N\over 2}+d$.

Thus, it is easiest to understand for $N$ even.

We can take advantage of the fact that $z \to -1/4z$ and $z\to z+1$ generate $\Gamma_0(4)$, and Poisson summation, to prove this. A new ingredient, in addition to the fact that Gaussians are essentially their own Fourier transforms, is Hecke's identity, namely, that on $\mathbb R^n$, functions $P(x)e^{-\pi |x|^2}$ (with $x\in \mathbb R^n$) with $P$ harmonic homogeneous of degree $d$ are simply multiplied by $i^{-d}$ under Fourier transform.

EDIT: and it is certainly holomorphic, if we express it more clearly in terms of the complex variable $z\in \mathfrak H$. It vanishes at the cusp $i\infty$ *visibly* because its $0$th Fourier coefficient is indeed $0$, because $P(0,0)=0$. There is a not-completely-trivial computation to be done to show that it vanishes at the other cusps (inequivalent to $i\infty$).

Answer (score 2):

This is an example taken from Zagier's "Introduction to Modular Forms", page 246 Section C. If you read Section E beginning on page 249, Zagier introduces the differential operator $F_\nu(f,g)$ of H. Cohen. If $f$ and $g$ are modular forms of a particular subgroup of weights $k$ and $l$ respectively, then 
$F_\nu$ maps to a cuspform of weight $k+l+2\nu$. It is then pointed out on page 250 that
$$\frac{8}{3}F_2(\vartheta,\vartheta)=\theta(z)$$where $\vartheta(z)=\sum_{n\in{Z}}q^{n^2}$. Since $\vartheta(z)$ is of weight 1/2 on $\Gamma(4)$, $\theta(z)$ is indeed a modular form of weight 5 and a cusp form since it's constant term is $0$.

Comment: A small quibble: the vanishing of the constant term of the Fourier expansion "at infinity" does indeed partly certify that it's a cuspform, but the other (inequivalent) cusps need to be checked, also, since there are holomorphic modular forms vanishing at some but not all cusps. But, in fact, harmonic theta series are indeed cuspforms for non-trivial harmonic polynomial.